# running ARM- fullsystem on gem5

Tags: gem5

0

I am trying to run ARM-full_system on gem5.when I enter this command for Performance : {root@farideh-S551LN:/home/farideh/gem5# ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu="minor" --num-cores=1 --disk-image=/home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --kernel=/home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64.20170616}

the terminal shows:

{gem5 Simulator System. http://gem5.org gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details. gem5 compiled May 1 2019 08:46:14 gem5 started Jun 2 2019 11:49:47 gem5 executing on farideh-S551LN, pid 7162 command line: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu=minor --num-cores=1 --disk-image=/home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --kernel=/home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64.20170616 Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (2048 Mbytes) info: kernel located at: /home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64.20170616 warn: Bootloader entry point 0x10 overriding reset address 0 warn: Highest ARM exception-level set to AArch32 but bootloader is for AArch64. Assuming you wanted these to match. system.vncserver: Listening for connections on port 5900 system.terminal: Listening for connections on port 3456 0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000 info: Using bootloader at address 0x10 info: Using kernel entry physical address at 0x80080000 info: Loading DTB file: /home/farideh/gem5/m5out/system.dtb at address 0x88000000 warn: Existing EnergyCtrl, but no enabled DVFSHandler found. info: Entering event queue @ 0. Starting simulation... warn: ClockedObject: Already in the requested power state, request ignored warn: SCReg: Access to unknown device dcc0:site0:pos0:fn7:dev0}

then I enter telnet 127.0.0.1 3456 in an other terminal and it shows:Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to localhost. Escape character is '^]'. ==== m5 slave terminal: Terminal 0 ==== }

after several times I confront by this error about telnet:Connection closed by foreign host. and another terminal , I see this:

root@farideh-S551LN:/home/farideh/gem5# ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu="minor" --num-cores=1 --disk-image=/home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --kernel=/home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64.20170616 gem5 Simulator System. http://gem5.org gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 compiled May 1 2019 08:46:14 gem5 started Jun 2 2019 11:49:47 gem5 executing on farideh-S551LN, pid 7162 command line: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu=minor --num-cores=1 --disk-image=/home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --kernel=/home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64.20170616

Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (2048 Mbytes) info: kernel located at: /home/farideh/Downloads/fullsystem/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64.20170616 warn: Bootloader entry point 0x10 overriding reset address 0 warn: Highest ARM exception-level set to AArch32 but bootloader is for AArch64. Assuming you wanted these to match. system.vncserver: Listening for connections on port 5900 system.terminal: Listening for connections on port 3456 0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000 info: Using bootloader at address 0x10 info: Using kernel entry physical address at 0x80080000 info: Loading DTB file: /home/farideh/gem5/m5out/system.dtb at address 0x88000000 warn: Existing EnergyCtrl, but no enabled DVFSHandler found. info: Entering event queue @ 0. Starting simulation... warn: ClockedObject: Already in the requested power state, request ignored warn: SCReg: Access to unknown device dcc0:site0:pos0:fn7:dev0 33342160250: system.terminal: attach terminal 0 49510353000: system.terminal: detach terminal 0 62922704750: system.terminal: attach terminal 0 warn: Tried to read RealView I/O at offset 0x60 that doesn't exist warn: Tried to read RealView I/O at offset 0x48 that doesn't exist warn: Tried to write RVIO at offset 0xa8 (data 0) that doesn't exist simulate() limit reached @ 18446744073709551615 root@farideh-S551LN:/home/farideh/gem5#

I do not know that Arm-fullsystem runs or not and why is telnet shows Connection closed by foreign host?

Comment: Hi farideh, please reformat your post to use Markdown code blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and add what seems to be the the key error message to the title, possibly "simulate() limit reached". Also, [here is a fs.py setup that I have tested](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/39de6f6abf45c881ff5fc4f490fd225cadeba78c#gem5-buildroot-setup), you could try that first and then diff options out until you find exactly what makes your setup not work. Mailing list post at: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16594.html